# What is the best method to transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

In experimenting with view controllers in Swift 4, various searches show there are several different methods to move between view controllers.  I first starting using this code to open a new view controller:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registration2") as! ViewRegistration2
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but then I found this method:

```
performSeque(withIdentifier: "sequeName", sender: self)
```

With this method I had to create a segue and name it, which is fine, but I wanted to know which is best practice and/or is there a reason to use one method or the other?

Comment: Unrelated you can simplify your first example to `let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "registration2")` and `present(vc, animated: true)`.

Comment: One might prefer the latter so that the storyboard graphically represents the all the relationships between the scenes in your app. We might manually `present` where we have to (e.g. the view controller was instantiated via NIB). We might manually `instantiateViewController` when we’re doing something manual with the view controller later (e.g. view controller containment, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segues can only be used with storyboards. They are normally instantiated automatically, and created in the storyboard. You can also perform segues in code. 
When using segues, the storyboard instantiates the view controller and triggers the transition.

When you aren't using storyboards, you present view controllers with `UIViewController.present(:animated:completion:)`.

It looks like you are using storyboards, and in that case you should use segues, because the first code snippet is essentially doing what segues do.

Answer (score 0):

You can present ViewControllers using present function on code.
Like this.
self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)

If there are ViewControllers on Storyboard, performSeque is a good way.